# Difference between CloudBlobClient and BlobClient

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage

When developing .NET Core for azure in C# in what circumstances should one use `CloudBlobClient` (nuget: Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob) vs `BlobClient` (nuget: Azure.Storage.Blobs).

Comment: Things changed over the years and from library to library. I would say that the main difference is related to new features / and some details of the implementation

Comment: Would you know more specifically the different features are?  Also does that mean the 'cloud' classes are the more outdated versions?

Comment: Hi Mark, it's hard to say because you didn't specify which Nuget Package you're using. But the latest and the one you should be using is "Azure.Storage.Blobs" 12.x

Comment: about comparing the features, maybe a better place to ask would be https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/

Comment: Ok thank you.  Would you happen to know if the CloudTable classes are the most up to date ones since I was unable to find any class that was simply Table client like the Blobs and Queues have?

Comment: it's because they are now under cosmos db.https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table If you want to use the storage one, I'm afraid there's no "new" nuget for it. You'll need to try one check if works

Comment: @Mark, please include more information, like nuget package version.

Comment: Ahhh I see thank you.

Comment: seems that CloudBlobClient is deprecated; link to it gets forwarded to `.Net Legacy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient?view=azure-dotnet-legacy&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet

Comment: this seems to be the most up to date reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet